# Different summaries at different levels in org-columns

Tags: org-mode, column, sexp

I'm trying to use `org-mode` for keeping track of my grades in university. My grades are all numerical from 0 to 10. I want the column view to output my average score and the final grade of each subject, but there is one subject where the final grade is calculated by summing instead of averaging. I want to get something like this

```
|Item         | Grade|
|-------------|------|
|* My degree  | 6.88 |
|** Subject 1 | 8.25 |
|*** Exam 1   | 9.5  |
|*** Exam 2   | 7    |
|** Subject 2 | 5.5  |
|*** Exam 1   | 3    |
|*** Exam 2   | 2.5  |
```

I tried setting the `GRADE` column but it did nothing:

```
* My degree
  :PROPERTIES:
  :COLUMNS: %ITEM %GRADE{mean;%.2f}
  :END:
** Subject 1
*** Exam 1
    :PROPERTIES:
    :GRADE: 9.5
    :END:
*** Exam 2
    :PROPERTIES:
    :GRADE: 7
    :END:
** Subject 2
   :PROPERTIES:
   :COLUMNS+: %GRADE{+;%.2f}
   :END:
*** Exam 1
    :PROPERTIES:
    :GRADE: 3
    :END:
*** Exam 2
    :PROPERTIES:
    :GRADE: 2.5
    :END:
```

I also tried using an Elisp sexp inside the properties as a workaround to get the sum by averaging scaled values, like this

```
:GRADE: %(* 2 2.5)
```

But the sexp doesn't get evaluated and the summary treats it as 0.

Is there an easy way to achieve what I want?